# Leaftlet dont show the map

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps

I want to display a map on android device. I see the zoom controller and a market. But the map is not displayed.

I follow the leftlet example, if I pass my code in a html the map is displayed but not in android.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVBJd.png)

Activity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)
    Log.d("----->Map", "")
    // init webView

    // displaying content in WebView from html file that stored in assets folder
    webView = map_location
    //webView.clearCache(true)
    //webView.clearHistory()


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/map.html");



}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="./leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./leaflet.css">


    <style>
    body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
     html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100vw; }

    </style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

    var map = L.map('map').setView([41.66, -4.72], 10);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);

    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

    //L.control.scale().addTo(map);
    L.marker([41.66, -4.71], {draggable: true}).addTo(map);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect the full map could be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Actually the <div> is shows but the map "the street the names.." are not.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, I just create the webview when I was testing the library of leaftlet but I forgot to give the internet permissions to the app, this make the full map were displayed